# Set focus to input element angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I got a student database with input text element. While the page is loaded a student must be highlighted with input text focussed.

I added a dynamic class that will set the focus if set true. If i map it with a static class it works fine. If i map it with dynamic class, it doesnt.

What is the right way i can pick the dynamic class for the directive.

[Here is my JSFIDDLE CODE](https://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/0wmjy6qs/1/)

Commenting these tds one at a time will help you to understand the issue

```
<td><input type="text" ng-class="student.focus?'focus-me':''"></td>  //dynamic class
 <td><input type="text" class="focus-me"></td> // static class
```

Comment: I got the answer https://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/0wmjy6qs/2/

Comment: If anyone can help me out with dynamic class loading, i would highly appreciate.

Comment: ng-if triggers many issues. Suggest not to use ng-if, instead use ng-class.

Answer (score 0):

[This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0wmjy6qs/5/) could help you understand how to properly set a class using ng-class.

```
<input type="text" ng-class="{'focus-me':student.focus}">
```

When value of student.focus is true, 'focus-me' class get applied in input tag.

Answer (score 0):

At first try I would simply extend that directive:

```
  link: function(scope, element,attributes){
    if ($parse(attributes.focusMe)(scope)) {
        element[0].focus();
    }
  }
```

In html:

```
<td><input type="text" focus-me="student.focus"></td>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hph1sja2/